# ¿No será que falta el “lo” (el agua) entre *me* y *extrajo*?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, sintaxis, objetos-directos

> Un hombre en calzones, de semblante turbado, me cortó el paso y me
>   arrastró en volandas hasta el pozo. **Allí me extrajo solícito un cubo
>   de agua** y, acto seguido, corrió de nuevo a su casa escabullándose como
>   un ratón.

¿No será que falta el “lo” (el agua) entre *me* y *extrajo*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, porque `lo` es un pronombre, y como tal sustituye a un nombre que ha sido ya mencionado y tanto hablante como receptor entienden (`se refiere siempre a un sustantivo mencionado en el contexto que reproduce anafóricamente, para no tener que repetir el mismo sustantivo constantemente` <sup>1</sup>).

Dado que ese `lo` sustituiría al cubo de agua, su uso sería redundante, ya que en la misma frase se está mencionando al cubo de agua.

Podrías decir

> Yo quería un **cubo de agua** y ese hombre me **lo** extrajo solícito

porque eso es equivalente a

> Yo quería un **cubo de agua** y ese hombre me extrajo solícito un **cubo de agua**

que es para lo que sirve el pronombre, para evitar esa repetición. En el caso que citas en la pregunta esa repetición no existe y el objeto (el cubo de agua) no ha sido mencionado previamente, por lo que no se puede usar ahí un pronombre (a menos que quede claro por el contexto o texto que no se incluye en la cita que ese `lo` hace referencia al cubo).

---

1- [Pronombre personal neutro lo](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Lo%20pronombre%20neutro.htm)